# Dealing with dynamic variables in Mapping DataFlow in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am still struggeling with Mapping dataflow to make the flows more dynamic. When doing a toString(byName("static argument")) it seems to work nicely. Everything is good.

But I would like to dynamically add argument and create an array like the one on picture 1.

In picture 2 I am trying to switch out the static value with an object from the array . I Get the error: Column name function 'byName' does not accept column or argument parameters.

How will I be able to create an new array that contains objects from the RegexExtract(). The array should contain both empty values and non empty values.

[image]

[image]

The second image shows what I would like to do, but it does not let me. But I guess it should be possible to somehow with dynamic content lookup the values from the stream of data.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide your source and sink?

Comment: Just added an image of the four activities.